# How can I save Java Object and IO

Tags: java, swing, serialization

This HashMap is a information that I want save and transfer to other.

```
HashMap<String,City> labelMap;
```

City Object has ArrayList

```
    class City implements Serializable{
            ArrayList<Marker> markerList;
    City(){
        markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    }

    public void setMarker(Marker marker) {
        markerList.add(marker);
    }
}
```

and Marker class is JLabel Object

```
class Marker extends JLabel implements Serializable{

ImageIcon image;

private Point point;
private String textString;



Marker(Point point, String textString){

    this.point = point;
    this.textString = textString;
    image = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Icon/marker.png"));
    setIcon(image);
}

public Point getPoint() {
    return point;
}

public void setPoint(Point point) {
    this.point = point;
}

public String getTextString() {
    return textString;
}

public void setTextString(String textString) {
    this.textString = textString;
 }
}
```

So how do I save the HashMap with the above information to a file so I can load it or send it later?

I tried using serialization, but it does not work. Is there a way to effectively store Swing-based program objects?

Finally I solved.

Problem was not awt or swing based.

The string I got from Jlabel was not English, but it did not matter if it was English, but it was an error if it was not English. So Jlabel.setText = ""; I made Jlabel's text blank, and then serialized non-English characters to fix it.

After all, the problem was with JLabel.getText when it took a non-English character and serialized it

Comment: *"Is there a way to effectively store Swing-based program objects?"* The approach is not to store the component itself, but it's content or state. E.G. For a text field, the string content. For a check box, a boolean representing if it is selected. For this custom label, the two attributes, `point` and `textString` (perhaps make a serializable POJO containing just those two objects). BTW - I'd avoid that form of serialization in favor of XML.

Comment: There are good reasons why Swing components (like `JLabel`) are not serializable ...

Comment: You said "I tried using serialization, but it does not work". Please share your [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), your [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) in the form of a [MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/), and why [it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) including error messages and/or stack traces so that those who read your question can better help you.

Comment: @D.B. Great advice, especially *"..in the form of a MCVE"*. A tip: `[mcve]` in a comment automatically expands to [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Finally I sovled.
Problem was not awt or swing based.

The string I got from Jlabel was not English, it did not matter if it was English, but it was an error if it was not English. So Jlabel.setText = ""; I made Jlabel's text blank, and then serialized non-English characters to fix it.

After all, the problem was with JLabel.getText when it took a non-English character and serialized it